# Кавычка в тексте для замены

Tags: bat

Вот есть файл newfile1.tex. Из него нужно удалить все вхождения

`\string"`

и результат сохранить как newfile1.tex. Я рассматриваю это как замена нужных участков кода пустым текстом с соответствующим сохранением. Написал такой батник:

```
echo off
rem http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi? 
forum=62&active=15&topic=27959&start=400
rem устанавливаю в качестве рабочей папки 
папку, в который находится
rem данный батник
cd /d %0\..
SetLocal EnableExtensions 
EnableDelayedExpansion 

Set infile=newfile1.tex
Set outFile=newfile0.tex 
Set find=\string"
Set replace=

for /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%n in 
("%infile%") do (  
set "LINE=%%n" 
echo=!LINE:%find%=%replace%!>>"%outFile%" 
 ) 
del newfile1.tex

rem файл 2.txt может и отсутствовать в 
rem папке, при этом файл 2.txt при 
rem исполнении 
rem этого батника.
```

Все работает, пока в заменяемом тексте отсутствует кавычка. Подскажите, плиз, как правильно?

Comment: У вас неправильно представлен код: 3 слова **SetLocal EnableExtensions 
EnableDelayedExpansion**  должны идти в одну строку. Аналогично для парсера **for /F**. Кроме того переменная **replace** не нужна. То есть строковое преобразование должно выглядеть так **echo.!LINE:%find%=!>>%outFile%**

Comment: По поводу трех слов, это просто тут так выглядит, в батнике в одной строке.  С for /F не понял, должно же быть так: `for /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%n in ("%infile%") do ( ` - это все в одной строке, да?

Comment: Да, это я и имел в виду, говоря что код некорректно отображен.

Comment: @Daemon-5, ваши коррективы из текста "sok" lodka

posle делают LINE:sok Set replace=bar= 
LINE:sok Set replace=bar=

Answer (score 1):

Код отработал без проблем. И конечно же в такой простой версии автозамены отсутствует обработка пустых строк

```
echo off
cd /d %0\..
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 

Set infile=newfile1.tex
Set outFile=newfile0.tex

Set find=\string"
Set replace=

for /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%n in ("%infile%") do (
set "LINE=%%n"
set "LINE=!LINE:%find%=!"
echo.!LINE!>>%outFile%
)
```

Comment: большой сенкс, Слушайте, попутно, чтоб не начинать новую тему. Как / заменить на \? Батники из этой темы / находить-то находят, удаляют его. А вот нужный символ не вставляют.

Comment: При попытке / заменить латинской буквой получаю то же самое. Это значит, я неправильно задал подлежащий замене объект.

Comment: Нет, / удаляется. Не происходит замены.

Comment: Данный пример приведен для **удаления** символов. Если же надо **заменить**, то 3-ю снизу строку следует заменить на **set "LINE=!LINE:%find%=%replace%!"**, и конечно же изменить переменные **find** и **replace** на необходимые. Проверил - замена тоже работает и проблем не возникает.

Comment: Все работает, еще раз спасибо. Все-таки последний код круче: замену можно приспособить для удаления, а вот наоборот - уже нет.

Comment: Новая ерунда. Выяснилось, что заменяются только отдельно стоящие /. Короче, есть строка C:/DocLyX/newfile8.tex. Мне нужно в ней поменять / на \. Помогите, пожалуйста.